# Linq to Sql in mvc 4

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having some problems editing an object in the mvc4 framework using linq to sql.
The "tbBoeking" object has been generated by Visual Studio 2010 and resides in a .dbml file. It has just been generated and no alterations have been made to it or the database.

Code in BoekingController.cs:

```
//This class has been generated and resides in a .dbml file
private DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

//Display edit form
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    tbBoeking boeking = db.tbBoekings.Single(p => p.boeknummer == id);
    if (boeking == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(boeking);
}

//Process changes made in form
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(tbBoeking boeking)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.tbBoekings.Attach(boeking, true);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(boeking);
}
```

Displaying the edit form works fine but when I press submit and the second Edit() is called things go wrong:
On db.submitchanges() I get an error which simply states:
"Row not found or changed".

I have read a few other posts about this error but they were not helpful for me. I think I'm making some basic mistake with Linq-to-sql or concurrency. Am I using Attach() in the wrong place or is it something else?

Thanks in advance,

Blight

Comment: What if you first get the current `boeking` from the database and use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548972) of `Attach`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is all of the required information filled in? Also, do you have some sort of timestamp that might need updated. I have heard of the code ignoring the asUpdated flag if a versioning system is in place.  That error can be very generic, so checking some other things can help

If the above suggestions do not help, then I would run a SQL profiler trace to see the SQL that is being fed to the server.

Comment: All fields except the ID are not required, the form only uses a hidden field for ID and a text field with a date value. When I check to see what object is given to Edit(), only those values are filled, the rest is null.